# AutoLayout: different OS X versions, different behaviors?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I'm developing an app for OS X which shows a small window (uses Auto Layout) when exiting. The window's size is about 550 x 290 pixels and it's fixed.

But I'm facing a behavior that seems pretty strange to me:

- Starting the app on OS X 10.7: the size of the small window is about as triple as large as it should be (width and height)
- Starting the app on OS X 10.8: the width of the window fits but its height is still about as twice as it should be
- Starting the app on OS X 10.9: the window has the size as I've designed it
- Starting the app on OS X 10.0: same (correct) behavior as with 10.9

I've re-set all constraints to correct settings (Xcode shows no layout issues). Can somebody give me a hint what might be happening there?

I'm absolutely sure that there are no other (conflicting or modifying) constraints within the view.

**Update**

Below you can find an image containing all constraints of the window. The constraints of the window itself (min and max size) have been set to the current (expected) size.
The image on the left side has been pinned to the bottom, the left and the top and its scaling behavior has been set to `proportionally down`. So the image should not be the source of the issue.

[image: The constaints of my window]

Comment: You have to show what the constraints actually are. What is in the window? Is anything in it also larger than you expect (e.g. an image that's scaled up)?

Comment: What happens if you use the size inspector to constrain the window's maximum size to be the expected size?

Comment: @JWWalker The constraints for the minimum and maximum size have been set to the current size.

Comment: @KenThomases I have updated my question and put an image into it to show the constraints of the window and its views, respectively.

Comment: The image view may indeed be the problem. Setting it to scale down doesn't mean it necessarily will. If its compression resistance priority is greater than (or equal to) 500 (`NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut`), then auto layout will (may) prefer to change the window size rather than compress/scale down the image. Is the image view in fact showing a large image?

Comment: Nope. The size of the image is always the same (it's small).

Comment: A little progress: The asset catalog contained the image in two sizes (1x and 2x). I removed the 2x image and Lion shows the correct height of the window. In this case you were right, Ken. But the width of the window is still way to large.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works. I think it was a combination of the 2x image within the assets catalog (caused the doubled height) and the labels within the view. The labels contain so much text that they either have to wrap it automatically or stretch them until the content fits (Lion and Mountain Lion seem to do so).

I've added the `width` constraint to both labels and fixed it at its current value (as given in the Interface Builder). This works for me as AutoLayout seems to keep the label's width and wraps their content (as expected).

Thanks a lot for the hints.